# My question is about combinatorics probability of arrays of distinct playing cards

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A casino adopts a 5 by 5 array of (distinct) playing cards as its decorative theme (to be displayed throughout). How many such arrays are there consisting of 8 spades, 7 clubs, 6 hearts, and 4 diamonds?

I was thinking its ((25 c 5) *5!)^5 because there are five ways to choose cards for each row arranging 5! factorial times and we do this 5 times for 5 arrays.

Comment: Please learn to use $\LaTeX$ from https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note how your train of thought does not take into account the restrictions imposed on the number of spades, hearts, clubs and diamonds.

You first need to consider the

$${13\choose 8}{13\choose 7}{13\choose 6}{13\choose 4} $$

Ways of picking the cards. Then you have to arrange them.

The easiest way is to think of the $5$ rows as one single super row of $25$ slots. Then there are $25! $ ways of doing that. You can also go with combinations, but not exactly like you did,  because as soon as you arrange the first row, you only have $20$ cards left for the second row, then $15$ for the third, ...

Comment: So what your saying is that we multiply the way of picking cards by 25! gives us the number of arrays because there are no restrictions on the rows

Comment: Exactly; the only restrictions are on the total cards

Comment: @yasky but note how using combinations would also work, just not those specific combinations